# Raspberry Pi project with sound concatenation based on date/time and events

Tags: audio, connection, memory, real-time

I'm thinking about making my first Raspberry Pi project and have some questions regarding what I will need to be able to complete this project.

The end result should be a sound based machine with two buttons, which is able to run 24/7.

If you press button number one, it will tell you the time and date with a greeting, read in my voice. For example: "Hello grandma, todays date is [XX/XX/XX] and the time is [XX:XX]."

If you press the second button, it will tell you all the pre-programmed events for the next 30 days, for example birthdays or appointments. It would sound something like this: "In [6] days, [it's Madeleins birthday.] In [25] days, [you have an appointment at the hospital at 5 o'clock]", where diffrent sound files are concatenated (or read up after eachother in the correct order). The sound files are manually recorded by myself and updated every month or so, based on my grandmothers plans.

This machine is meant for my grandmother who has trouble remembering certain things these days, and has problems with her [macula of retina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macula_of_retina), making her eyesight very limited.

Here are some additional requirements for the machine:

1. Memory card where I can store sounds files in a appropriate format.
2. A battery that lasts for 1 year+, or some sort of rechargable battery, or a way to hook this up to a standard home power outlet. (Which is best?)
3. A speaker to play the sound.
4. OS/Extra component to handle real-time.
5. Buttons
6. Chassi
7. Cable/extra component to be able to plug it into a computer for programming and adding new sound files and events.

As this is my first RP project, I'm not sure what parts i need to complete it.

So my question is, what Raspberry Pi version/parts/components are best suited to complete this project?

I know C# decently and I'm planning on programming the computer myself, is there any E-book/web-based recource that's recommended for learning how to program a Raspberry Pi?

Also, if you have any tips regarding a certain aspect of this project I would love to hear it.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi StackExchange.  Unfortunately your question isn't on topic here, and will probably be closed.  This site isn't a general forum. If you haven't already, please take a look at the Help Center: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: As your question is rather broad, you may be better off asking your question on the [raspberry pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/index.php). However, if you have a _specific_ issue when implementing your project, rather than the project overall, then feel free to ask about that on SE. HTH :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is very achievable.

I suggest you look at Python for the programming language and use a Pi 2 (the latest Pi).

The Pi has no speakers so you will need to add something like a USB speaker.

I suggest you look through issues of the [MagPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/) magazine which should give you all the additional information you need.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the answer. When I buy a RP 2, will I get cables to be able to plug it into my computer for programming it? And does RP 2 come with a USB slot, and with enough memory to enable a machine like this to work?

Comment: Depends on whether you buy the bare board or a kit.  Google for options.  https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/